# Possible Methods for tracking moving vehicles with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I am doing a project where I have to be able to track the movement of cars entering and exiting an area. I am using the OpenCV library with C++. After searching through all of the features I am unsure on which methods to use. I was thinking of using opticalFlow for the movement and setting up two regions of interest for the entry/exit, but I am unsure on how to detect the actual vehicle. Can anyone more experienced with OpenCV offer me some insight?

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start by detecting objects that enter the image. I guess you have a fixed camera that doesn't move. If so, you can start with background subtraction techniques: with the fixed camera, and without any objects moving to/from the image, you estimate a Gaussian model for the color (or some other properties)  of every pixel in the image. Afterwards you'll probably need to re-estimate the model in order to make it adapt to changes in, say, the illumination. Once you estimated the model, you can detect objects entering and moving from the image, since pixels there will have values other than the expected. Then, retake the Optical Flow to track them in the image.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have to wait to try and implement this at a later date. getting swamped with alot of written work for a research paper

Answer (score 1):

Genis's answer is defiantly a good one. Background subtraction and then blob detection is probably the best approach if there is not going to be large changes in lighting conditions and if the camera is at an angle where the car objects wont overlap.

Personally I would go for straight up optical flow and segment on the vectors. You could run optical flow on a Sobel edge image if processing time is critical.

There are many ways to skin this cat. Perhaps if you posted some screen captures of the scene you would get more specific solutions.

Comment: I will try these methods as soon as I can thanks for the help it has taken a load of my mind for now :)